# NullPointerException in nested array

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

It is in my nested array. Basically I want to retrieve in `arrayIWantThisCat`

> [10 {1,2,3,4} , 20 {5,6,7,8}]

```
String[][] arrayIWantThisCat;
String[] arrayAddendAmounts;

try {
    SQLiteAdapter info = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    info.open();
    alAddends = info.getFinalCategorysTagAddend();
    info.close();
    //  Array holds all unique Addend amounts
    arrayAddendAmounts = alAddends.toArray(new String[alAddends.size()]);               
 } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
    Log.d("TAG", "failure to get data,", e);
    return;
 }

 int numberOfAddends = arrayAddendAmounts.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAddends; i++) {
try {
    SQLiteAdapter info = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    info.open();
    alWhatCatDoYouWant = info.getFinalCategorysCatIDsBasedOnAddend(arrayAddendAmounts[i]);
    info.close();

         ***//  This is where the issue is ( Nested Array )***
    arrayIWantThisCat[i] = alWhatCatDoYouWant.toArray(new String[alWhatCatDoYouWant.size()]);               
    } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
    Log.d("TAG", "failure to get data,", e);
    return;
    }
}
```

Comment: these are some heavy variables/method names you have in there :p `info.getFinalCategorysCatIDsBasedOnAddend(arrayAddendAmounts[i]);` made my brain twist a little

Comment: For clarity, I would suggest you post the whole stack trace. Then people will know exactly **where** your `NullPointerException` occurs, and *maybe* why.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I marked it with  ***//  This is where the issue is ( Nested Array )***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized `arrayIWantThisCat` in your code, yet you're referencing it by index, in this line:

```
arrayIWantThisCat[i] = alWhatCatDoYouWant.toArray(new String[alWhatCatDoYouWant.size()]);
```

This is likely to cause your `NullPointerException`.

You probably want to initialize it with a 1st level size, such as:

```
arrayIWantThisCat = new String[myFirstLevelSize][];
```

... before accessing its index `i`, which can equal up to `myFirstLevelSize - 1`.

Comment: Actually that one is "initialized", as far as `alWhatCatDoYouWant = info.getFinalCategorysCatIDsBasedOnAddend(arrayAddendAmounts[i]);` initializes it. Of course, who knows...

Comment: Yeah that's true. However, it could be null.

Comment: Just commented OP for whole stack trace. It **could** be `alWhatCatDoYouWant` (my eyes are bleeding BTW). It could be whatever. I was assuming - until evidence of the contrary - that the rest of the code was running fine.

Comment: ok so arrayIWantThisCat = new String[numberOfAddends][]; works.  And while my variable names are sudo names what would you change about them.  I'm always willing to re-look at things.

Comment: @Rick glad it works. Your naming is very unclear as per the scope of your variables. I suggest you take a look at the Java [coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) to get some hints, and in general, look around, you'll see how "talkative" code helps scalability etc. Which still implies you use **pseudo**-names in a way (yeah, trolling you a bit :D sorry).

Answer (score 0):

You have not created a array, but just a reference which is null. This is causing NullPointerException to occur.

```
String[][] arrayIWantThisCat;
```

Answer (score 0):

`String[][] arrayIWantThisCat = new String[0][];`

should fix it, use org.apache.commons.ArrayUtils to resize it or a Set/List instead.